# Page 403 Forbidden for root directory for Deny from all in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have next `.htaccess` in root directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
<Files index.php>
Allow from all
</Files>
```

And get Page 403 Forbidden for `www.example.com` instead of `www.example.com/index.php`.

URL `www.example.com/index.php` is available.

Access to all files in the root directory is closed. These files are generated by scripts, the file names are unknown.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <Files index.php>
> Allow from all
> </Files>
> ```

Try the following instead:

```
<FilesMatch "^(index\.php)?$">
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

**UPDATE:** Added missed *anchors*!

(Although I would assume you are on Apache 2.4, so you should be using the corresponding `Require` directives instead of `Order`, `Deny` and `Allow`.)

Alternatively, replace all you existing directives with the following:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^(index\.php)?$ - [F]
```

This allows access to both `example.com/` and `example.com/index.php`. To block direct access to `index.php` then try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ - [F]
```

mod_dir (ie. "DirectoryIndex") is processed after mod_rewrite.

---

> ```
> RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
> ```

This rule is redundant, it should be handled by `DirectoryIndex` instead.

---

**UPDATE:**

> RewriteRule !^(index.php)?$ - [F] works, but I add RewriteRule !^(index2.php)?$ - [F] for second file index2.php and It dont work... I am getting 403 error for [www.example.com/index2.php..](http://www.example.com/index2.php..). I need access to several files

By adding another rule it would end up blocking both URLs. Since one or other rule will always be successful.

You can use regex *alternation* in a single rule. For example:

```
RewriteRule !^(index\.php|index2\.php)?$ - [F]
```

The same regex could be used in the `<FilesMatch>` container above.

Or, if you have many such exceptions, it might be more readable to have multiple *conditions*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=index2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=index3.php
RewriteRule !^$ - [F]
```

Note, however, like your original rule, this also blocks URLs in "subdirectories", not just the root directory.

Comment: <FilesMatch "(index\.php)?">Allow from all</FilesMatch> gives access to all files. I don't need it.

Comment: RewriteRule !^(index\.php)?$ - [F] works, but I add RewriteRule !^(index2\.php)?$ - [F] for second file index2.php and It dont work... I am getting 403 error for www.example.com/index2.php... I need access to several files

Comment: @VerySimple192347 Sorry, I had missed the _anchors_ on that initial regex. It should read `<FilesMatch "^(index\.php)?$">`. Simply repeating that rule for `index2.php` would result in both files being blocked. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @VerySimple192347 To confirm... these rules block requests for subdirectories as well (as does your original rule), not just the root directory. Is that OK?